# ASP.Net MVC3 Razor website Session Variables disappearing in CHROME

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, session-variables, telerik-mvc

I am working on an website with ASP.net MVC3 razor using the Telerik MVC open source controls.
I keep track of the logged in user with the help of session variables. 
eg - After the user logs in

```
        Session.Add("LoggedInUserId", loggedInUser.BillerUserId);
        Session.Add("LoggedInUserEmail", loggedInUser.BillerUserEmail);
        Session.Add("LoggedInUserType", loggedInUser.BillerUserTypeId);
        Session.Add("LoggedInUser", loggedInUser);
```

Inside the ActionResult for every controller, I look at the session variables and decide if the user has access/permissions to the view. This approach works fine for IE & Firefox. But I face a strange situation in Chrome. When using Chrome after the Session variables are set, I can successfully load the first View ( session variables have their values) . But after this if the user clicks on the menu which will redirect him to a different view (inside any controller) the **Session variables are null.** 
I access the session as -

HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUser"]

I am using the latest version of Chrome (17.0) with Cookies & Javascript enabled.
Please help...

Thanks,
sdd

Comment: Have you looked at your HTTP headers being sent between your server and Chrome? It sounds like the ASP.NET session cookie isn't sticking and a new session is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add favicon.ico to the root folder of your site.
See [this article](http://tobiefysh.blogspot.com/2010/12/chrome-is-eating-my-session-varibles-or.html).